# In hash collision, how does CPython know which value is stored at index HASHVALUE and which value is stored at RESOLUTIONINDEX

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, collision

If I have a dict, for example `{ key1 : value1, key2 : value2,..., key17:value17 }`, and 2 keys give out the same hash, say key13 and key5 both give out 12 when hashed, as I understand it python implements a collision resolution method (open addressing if I'm not mistaken) to solve that problem.
So, say value5 will be stored at index 12 and value13 will be stored in another open index determined by the collision resolution method.

Here's the tricky part I get befuddled by: In order to retrieve the value (from key5 for example), does the CPython interpreter hash the key and retrieve the value from index HASHVALUE?
That can't be right, because then how would the interpreter know if value13 belong to key5, or is it located in a different index due to collision?

I tried looking at the C code from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1041

and the function seems to be

```
PyObject *
PyDict_GetItem(PyObject *op, PyObject *key)
{
    Py_hash_t hash;
    PyDictObject *mp = (PyDictObject *)op;
    PyDictKeyEntry *ep;
    PyThreadState *tstate;
    PyObject **value_addr;

    if (!PyDict_Check(op))
        return NULL;
    if (!PyUnicode_CheckExact(key) ||
        (hash = ((PyASCIIObject *) key)->hash) == -1)
    {
        hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
        if (hash == -1) {
            PyErr_Clear();
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    #/* We can arrive here with a NULL tstate during initialization: try
       #running "python -Wi" for an example related to string interning.
       #Let's just hope that no exception occurs then...  This must be
       #_PyThreadState_Current and not PyThreadState_GET() because in debug
       #mode, the latter complains if tstate is NULL. */
    tstate = (PyThreadState*)_Py_atomic_load_relaxed(
        &_PyThreadState_Current);
    if (tstate != NULL && tstate->curexc_type != NULL) {
       # /* preserve the existing exception */
        PyObject *err_type, *err_value, *err_tb;
        PyErr_Fetch(&err_type, &err_value, &err_tb);
        ep = (mp->ma_keys->dk_lookup)(mp, key, hash, &value_addr);
       # /* ignore errors */
        PyErr_Restore(err_type, err_value, err_tb);
        if (ep == NULL)
            return NULL;
    }
    else {
        ep = (mp->ma_keys->dk_lookup)(mp, key, hash, &value_addr);
        if (ep == NULL) {
            PyErr_Clear();
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return *value_addr;
}
```

but my C knowledge is very lacking and I frankly don't understand what half of this says.

Comment: Value equality is used to distinguish between different keys that end up in the same bucket.

Comment: Do you mean that both the key and the value are stored under the same index?

Comment: Not necessarily, and such is secondary to a reliable hashtable; rather,  the correct key is always identified per '==' semantics (even when there is no collision).  The hash code merely applies to bucket distribution, not resolution.

Comment: This is answered in detail at around minute 8:50 in the talk [The mighty dictionary](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68), given by Brandon Craig Rhodes at PyCon 2010.

Comment: I see. In the case where the key isn't stored along with the value, what does the interpreter compare the key from `dict[key]` to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Keys are stored with their associated values

Each index into a CPython hash table is associated with a structure that includes three fields: the hash value, a key pointer, and a value pointer:

```
typedef struct {
    Py_ssize_t me_hash;
    PyObject *me_key;
    PyObject *me_value;
} PyDictEntry;
```

### How it works for a hash collision

In your scenario, `{hash5, key5, value5}` are stored at index `12`, and `{hash13, key13, value13}` are stored at an alternate index chosen by open-addressing collision resolution.

When looking up `key5` at index `12`, Python verifies that the key matches and then returns the associated `value5`.

Contrariwise, when first looking for `key13` at index `12`, Python notices that `key13 != key5` and will not return `value5`.  Instead, it jumps to the alternate index where `key13` matches and then returns the associated `value13`.

### Conclusion

You asked how does "CPython know which value is stored at index HASHVALUE and which value is stored at RESOLUTIONINDEX".  The answer is that values are stored with the associated keys, making it possible to know which value is associated with which key.